# Que esta equivocado en el siguiente ejercicio de RSA?

Tags: encriptación

He estado practicando RSA, y no se que esta pasando que al decencriptar no obtengo el plain text correcto

Adjuntaré las imagenes del procedimiento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow en Español. Te recomendamos que dar el recorrido [tour] y tengas conocimiento de como preguntar [ask].

Comment: Para responder a tu pregunta es necesario que coloques el código que llevas para dar una respuesta más especifica y poder etiquetar tu pregunta correctamente.